# EthereumJS returning wrong public key

Tags: wallets, ethereumjs, private-key, public-key

I'm using https://iancoleman.io/bip39/#english to generate a random 12 word mneumonic with the following settings.

- Mneumonic language: **English**
- Coin: **Ethereum**
- Derivation Path: **BIP44**

It generated the following mneumonic `movie diesel same toe bachelor acquire roast ghost siege thought possible scale`

The first address - public key - private key is the following
**Address:** `0x67D8641084F8088D5996E39Bae07F9Dc4130307F`
**Public Key:** `0x030c8931742732ca2e0956ecf385acc886a54428ad84eb884aa2c72f1008a2c858`
**Private Key:** `0x78f7e532bf8d7c79d8ef42c75a361f53a8db8c38e4cb1828788ef119c48f6896`
I wrote this to generate the same public key from the private key.

```js
var Wallet = require('ethereumjs-wallet')
var EthUtil = require('ethereumjs-util')

// Get a wallet instance from a private key
const privateKeyBuffer = EthUtil.toBuffer(
  '0x78f7e532bf8d7c79d8ef42c75a361f53a8db8c38e4cb1828788ef119c48f6896'
)
const wallet = Wallet.fromPrivateKey(privateKeyBuffer)

// Get a public key
const publicKey = wallet.getPublicKeyString()
console.log(publicKey)
```

the log statment prints `0x0c8931742732ca2e0956ecf385acc886a54428ad84eb884aa2c72f1008a2c8582bc50fd34eb9e111ae2969205d7af28e9b5050be4ae6ca43df74fc65b9af5803`

This is not the same public key for the corresponding private key, why is this?

Comment: `0x030c8931742732ca2e0956ecf385acc886a54428ad84eb884aa2c72f1008a2c858` is not a valid public key.

Answer (score 0):

> Public Key: `0x030c8931742732ca2e0956ecf385acc886a54428ad84eb884aa2c72f1008a2c858`

A public key consists of 512 bits, represented with a string of 128 hexadecimal characters.

Hence the above is not a valid public key.

> `0x0c8931742732ca2e0956ecf385acc886a54428ad84eb884aa2c72f1008a2c8582bc50fd34eb9e111ae2969205d7af28e9b5050be4ae6ca43df74fc65b9af5803` is not the same public key for the corresponding private key

This is in fact the correct public key for the private key given in the question.

Comment: In that case I must've misunderstood something from the website i was using and what it really generates. `EthUtil.privateToAddress(privateKeyBuffer)` does return the same address as the website does. Isn't the address supposed to match the last 20bytes of the public key though?

Comment: @Conviley: 40 bytes. And I'm pretty sure that it's supposed to be the hash of those 40 bytes.